# Matrix.itam((i,j)) does not work properly

Tags: python, function, artificial-intelligence, linear-regression

I'm working on linear regression algorithm with multiple variables using Numpy library for Matrix.
My problem is that matrix.item((i,j)) is not working properly.here is python shell:

```
>>> a=h(Data,0,Theta)
>>> a
matrix([[3.78]])
>>> a.item((0,0))
3.7800000000000002
```

As you see the output value is 0.0000000000000002 bigger than the real answer.

Comment: Even computers does not work properly!

Comment: That's a display thing, not a bug. The first output just truncates more aggressively for display.

Comment: I think with a more recent NumPy version, the same rounding behavior would have been applied both times.

Comment: @user2357112 i calculated it  manually and the correct answer is exactly 3.78

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: 3.78 isn't representable in binary. You're going to have to get used to floating point rounding behavior if you want to do any sort of numerical work on a computer. (Even if you switch to decimal, and completely wreck your performance in the process, you'll just end up with most of the same problems, but in decimal.)

Comment: @AmirparsaSal maybe read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25420021/9225671) on limitations of `float` data type or this: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This is not a bug, it's the default behavior.
- While displaying x it truncates the value.

Please check the below example.

```
>>> x = np.matrix(((3.7800000000000002)))

>>> x
matrix([[3.78]])

>>> x.item(0,0)
3.7800000000000002
```